# Creating a Graph from a lines AND a points shapefile in networkx using read_shp

Tags: qgis, shapefile, networkx, point

I am trying to use networkx for analysing networks which I represented in QGIS as a line shapefile and a point shapefile. If I import only the lines shapefile using networkx.read_shp('lines.shp') I can already do some of the analysis I want, but I cannot figure out how to do import also the point shapefile with the nodes. I need that because in some of my networks not all the edges go in a straight line from one node to the other and converting only the lines.shp networkx creates a node for each "bending" of the lines, and also because I would like to store in networkx both the coordinates and the attributes given to the points in the shapefile attribute table (exactly as when reading the lines.shp).

Both if I try networkx.read_shp('lines.shp','points.shp') or networkx.read_shp('points.shp') alone, I get the same error: "add_node() takes exactly 2 arguments (3 given)" referring to line 88 in https://networkx.github.io/documentation/stable/_modules/networkx/readwrite/nx_shp.html#read_shp ( net.add_node((g.GetPoint_2D(0)), attributes ).

Does anyone have suggestions on how to correctly read a point shapefile?

(In case that matters, I am using QGIS 2.18.17 with Python 2.7 and networkx 2.0)